# My arms hurt when riding

Tags: bike-fit

[image: bike fit on a road bike]

My lower back bends a lot and the weight goes to my arm. What is the problem?

Comment: Your arms are too stiff.

Comment: Can't tell from the photo, but you might check saddle tilt. If my saddle is sloped downwards towards the handlebars, I'll find myself sliding forward, which I have to resist with my arms. That can be tiring on the arms. My saddles are usually level so I don't slide around. Increasing core strength, flexibility, and triceps strength can help if the bike fit is good otherwise.

Comment: Can you try riding without the backpack for a bit?  That may be contributing, though it doesn't look heavy.

Answer (score 6):

We discussed your position a little in [Bicycles Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/214/the-velodrome).
It's possible your frame is one size too small - but we could see a number of possible adjustments that might help.

It looks like your saddle is set too far back and too low.  I would start by moving the saddle 5-10mm forward and 10-20mm up.

It also looks like you are pedalling with your toes on the pedal rather than the ball of your foot - this may be (or not) a subconscious compensation for your saddle being so far back.

Making this adjustment may result in needing a longer stem - but try it for a while first and see if you feel cramped.

There are also a couple of factors that are not necessarily related to bike fit.

The rounding of the lower back and 'collapsing' onto the arms can be related to poor core strength.  A stronger core and better posture will take weight off the arms.

Finally, your arms are very straight with elbows locked - this doesn't allow your arms to work as shock absorbers and transmits every bump up to your upper arms and shoulders.  Keeping a bend in your elbows helps reduce this type of fatigue/soreness (although places more demands on the core muscles).

Comment: And flip the stem to raise the bars some - especially if the saddle is moved a bit higher.  That might be all that's needed.  IMO a longer stem is likely to make the stiff-armed reaching for the bars worse.